# What is the difference between FormControl init methods?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

What is the difference between below methods:

```
input: new FormControl({}, inputValidatorFn())

input: [{}, inputValidatorFn()]

input: formBuilder.control({}, inputValidatorFn())
```

It seams to behave the same.

Or there is no difference at all?

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dzod2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be a bit brief to answer this one.

so your code to build the form,

```
fb.group({
      newFormControl: new FormControl({}, inputValidatorFn()),

      arrayNotation: [{}, inputValidatorFn()],

      input: fb.control({}, inputValidatorFn()),
    })
```

here you are using `fb.group()` method to build a group of controls. If you see `FormBuilder` class declaration you will see it has multiple methods `group()`, `control()` and `array()`

lets see the definition of group method,

**group()**: it takes two parameter (`controlsConfig` and `options`) and return a `FormGroup`.

```
/**
 * Construct a new `FormGroup` instance.

 * @param controlsConfig : A collection of child controls. 
The key for each child is the name, under which it is registered.

 * @param options : Configuration options object for the `FormGroup`. 
With the help of this we can set validators, asyncValidators for that `FormGroup`.
*/


group(controlsConfig: {
    [key: string]: any;
}, options?: AbstractControlOptions | {
    [key: string]: any;
} | null): FormGroup;
```

you can build a control in two ways.

`controlsConfig` is an object of **`any`** type and we pass a collection of child controls.

> `fb.group()` function understands that `[{}, inputValidatorFn()]` is a `FormControl`. thus it works.

we can always create a control,

1. with **FormControl** - `new FormControl({}, inputValidatorFn())`
2. with **FormBuilder** service - `fb.control({}, inputValidatorFn())`

They all return a `FormControl` that we need, so, there is no difference here.

A line from [**Angular documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#generating-form-controls-with-formbuilder) may be helpful.

> Creating form control instances manually can become repetitive when
>   dealing with multiple forms. The FormBuilder service provides
>   convenient methods for generating controls.

so, for larger form we use array init form like yours `[{}, inputValidatorFn()]` of `FormBuilder` service.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference at all.

Initializing a form control using **FormBuilder** uses the **Factory Design Pattern**, which is a better way of coding.

The [angular site](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) explains,

> The FormBuilder provides syntactic sugar that shortens creating
>   instances of a FormControl, FormGroup, or FormArray. It reduces the
>   amount of boilerplate needed to build complex forms.

Comment: After this quote I still think array notation provides everything we need and is the shortest one.

Comment: Yeah, but when it comes to very large forms, it is better to use formBuilder since it reduces boilerplate

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon +1 for you point "FormBuilder uses the Factory Design Pattern"